# Bayesian Inference / Likelihood of Byte-stream

Tags: bayesian-estimation, maximum-likelihood-estimation

### Introduction

Let us consider the following problem; I receive a byte stream. The bytes are **correlated**, i.e.

1. It is possible that values will very quite close.
2. It is reasonable to assume that the stream may have some some spectral properties, i.e. exhibit only slow rate of change / specific frequencies.
3. The distribution is a priori unknown.

---

### My Question

How would you suggest I go about estimating the distribution of the the correlated stream / estimating the likelihood function for possible values?

Any suggestions or references will be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi: if you think that they are correlated you could model them as a time series using say an AR(1) and see how that goes. The AR(1) implies a correlation structure between successive elements and of course other AR models imply other ones so that's a start. This is not to imply that an AR(1) is the correct model. It was just an example.

Comment: Sounds great, any particular suggested reference, or just google?

Comment: Hi: The AR(1) is a model for the time domain so it's not gonna helpful as far as frequencies. If you're background in time series is not so much and you want to get an intro book, I would recommend this book: The Analysis of Time Series: An Introduction, Sixth Edition (Chapman & Hall/CRC Texts in Statistical Science) (9781584883173): Chris Chatfield: it doesn't cover just AR models but it certainly includes them. Another alternative is to google but then you'll get both the good and not so good.

Comment: At a quick glance, this doesn't look bad. https://www.econometrics-with-r.org/14-3-autoregressions.html.  I'm just always biased towards books because they tend to give the bigger picture. In fact,  Chatfield is particularly good at the "bigger picture" and less focused on the gory details.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will look them up